# Pipe insulation, pros and cons

Tags: plumbing, insulation, pipe, hot-water

Someone told me that pipe insulation is not necessary, rather he said it could cause more problems.

I'm under impression that he's making an excuse because he forgot to put it back.

**Any inputs, anyone?**

If there is no issues I'd rather have them on hot pipes to keep hot water hot.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining how pipe insulation could cause a problem. Is this the split foam insulation that is typically applied to pex or copper pipe?

Comment: Pipe insulation will help prevent them from freezing in an unheated crawl space.

Comment: I wouldn't say it would cause problems but rather that the benefit would not be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe insulation does not keep the water in the pipe “hot” between uses.

However, it will help keep the water “hot” while in use. That is to say, as the water travels down the uninsulated pipe, the water will loose more temperature than an insulated pipe. This may help in the sizing of your water heater.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Lee Sam.